# Need help forming SQLite join query

Tags: sql, join, sqlite

I've been able to make a query using MS Access 2010 that does just what I want but I am having trouble doing so in SQLite3. Here is the Access SQL

```
SELECT pubacc_lo.*
FROM pubacc_en 
LEFT JOIN pubacc_lo ON pubacc_en.call_sign = pubacc_lo.call_sign;
```

Basically it selects all of the columns in the pubacc_lo table and the rows where the call_sign fields are equal between the tables. **This does not select any of the pubacc_en data into the final query in MS Access.**

Playing around in SQLite 3, the closest I've gotten was

```
SELECT * FROM PUBACC_LO, PUBACC_EN WHERE PUBACC_en.call_sign=PUBACC_LO.call_sign
```

But this statement selects all of the data in the EN table along with the LO table (cross join?). I've tried some left outer joins but haven't had any luck. Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: The original syntax should work in SQLite3.  What results (or error message) do you get when you try it?

Comment: why not just use the same query as access? SQLite should give the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the same query as you got from Access. SQLite3 does support left outer joins.

As for your query, if you only want the fields from the LO table, then ask for that in your SELECT clause like this:

```
SELECT PUBACC_LO.* 
FROM PUBACC_LO, PUBACC_EN 
WHERE PUBACC_en.call_sign=PUBACC_LO.call_sign
```

but the problem here is that it will only return `call_signs` with entries in both tables, while the outer join from access will return all rows from `PUBACC_EN` irrespective of whether there is a corresponding `PUBACC_LO` entry..

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I'm not sure why I thought the Access code wouldn't work in SQlite3 but it indeed does, boy do I feel stupid now

Comment: Ok, well, can I suggest accepting an answer by clicking on the check mark against it - it'll help make sure your questions are answered quickly in future..

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT pubacc_lo.* FROM PUBACC_LO, PUBACC_EN WHERE UBACC_en.call_sign=PUBACC_LO.call_sign
```

If you only want to select pubbac_lo's field, this is what you can use.